# Angular app installing Error: Unexpected end of JSON input while parsing near '...//registry.npmjs.org/'

Tags: angular-cli, angular-cli-v7

I am very new to Angular. I have installed the Angular by using the command:

```
npm install -g @angular/cli
```

When I check the version of Angular it shows:

[image]

After on, I installed an Angular application by using: `ng new newApp`

I have got an error during app installation:

> Unexpected end of JSON input while parsing near
>   '...//registry.npmjs.org/'

Here is the image of what I have done:

[image]

You can find log content through this link:
https://drive.google.com/file/d/11MEWOcSaU4c-1879LuijRiXRvCu-cAIz/view?usp=sharing

Let me know where is the problem...

Comment: try to create a new project, again.

Comment: @Yoarthur I have tried it many times in different directories. But no any success...

Comment: delete the folder and all it's content, and try it again.

Comment: @RahmatAli clear npm cache using `npm cache clean` and then try creating a new application

Comment: @MohsinMehmood This trick worked for me. I have used `npm cache clean --force` and now it installed the new application. Buddy Thanks : )...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try clearing the npm cache first using the following command and then try creating a new ng application

```
npm cache clean --force
```