# Getting few errors in installing NativeScript Sidekick on Windows 10. Already installed the CLI full version previously

Tags: nativescript, sidekick

Trying to install NativeScript Sidekick in order to deploy the app on local device. I have already installed Full CLI and tns run works fine on emulator. Now Sidekick installation gives several errors and hangs.

Tried meeting all pre-reqs inclusing installing ITunes.

[Errors List on Windows 10](https://i.stack.imgur.com/O2KMJ.jpg)

Comment: Also what I understand from errors is either sidekick is not installed properly or does not have proper privileges.
Try these steps:

- Running sidekick as administrator

- Make sure you have proper internet connection and can access nativescript.org website

- Uninstall and install sidekick again

Comment: Thanks. I earlier tried running and installing as admin, but that did not help. Also checked the internet and site access. Just found the reason and posted the answer.

Answer (score 0):

I had to do the following to resolve this:

npm cache clean --force
tns setup cloud

After that sidekick executed fine. Did not have to reinstall sidekick.

Without cleaning cache there were so many errors, leading to Unexpected end of JSON input while parsing near '...//registry.npmjs.org/'

Following stackoverflow post helped:
[Agular app installing Error: Unexpected end of JSON input while parsing near '...//registry.npmjs.org/'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53916742/agular-app-installing-error-unexpected-end-of-json-input-while-parsing-near)